# How do I register an EventAggregator as a singleton in an MVVM app?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, prism, autofac, eventaggregator

Building my first MVVM application, and it's introducing some really powerful concepts, but at the same time it's a lot to learn at once. The issue I'm having right now is that event subscribers don't seem to be receiving the events when I publish them from another ViewModel.

I think I need to `new` up an EventAggregator in App.xaml.cs or in my `BootStrapper` class and then inject that instance into each ViewModel that needs to reference it. I think what's happening is that a new `IEventAggregator` is being created for each view model and I'm pubbing/subbing to different instances. Not sure if my disconnect is with the EventAggregator Pattern/Prism or DI/Autofac here.

Should I do something like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    //Add this...
    IEventAggregator eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //... and pass in here somehow?
        var window = new BootStrapper()
            .Bootstrap()
            .Resolve<AView>();

        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
public class BootStrapper
{
    //Add this...
    IEventAggregator eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();

    public IContainer Bootstrap()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();


        builder.RegisterType<AView>()
            .AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<AViewModel>()
            .AsSelf();

        builder.RegisterType<OtherViewModel>()
            .As<IOtherViewModel>();
        builder.RegisterType<ADataProvider>()
            .As<IADataProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<ADataService>()
            .As<IDataService<Account>>();

        //What I'm doing now
        builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>()
            .As<IEventAggregator>();

        //...and register instance here?

        builder.RegisterType<AccountSelectedEvent>()
            .AsSelf();

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Advice, references, or nudges in the right direction equally appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, and it was... embarrassingly simple. In my `BootStrapper`

#### Before

Type was registering fine, but was injecting a new instance each time an instance was requested, and so I was `pubbing` to one, `subbing` to another.

```
    builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>()
        .As<IEventAggregator>();
```

#### After

Oh my god.

```
    builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>()
        .As<IEventAggregator>()
        .SingleInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to either derive your bootstrapper from an existing container-specific bootstrapper that does all the prism registrations for you, or derive your application from one of the new container-specific `PrismApplication` classes that are going to replace the bootstrapper in future prism versions.

Give the [Prism Template Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BrianLagunas.PrismTemplatePack) a try, it creates a minimal, working app for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I ended up finding an autofac solution (see my answer) but this I think this is also a good approach.

Comment: Just be careful to register all the types you need, event aggregator is just one of many... https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/1ddcc52159f44f73a40c4bdbdf38c311f4cf9a6d/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismApplicationBase.cs#L114 and https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Autofac.Wpf/PrismApplication.cs